# How does Xena's chakram return to her after every throw?

Tags: xena

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7171/how-does-captain-americas-shield-work).  When Xena throws her chakram, how does it ricochet around the room and return to her?

Is it a magic weapon or does she have some ability or powers for this to work?

Comment: A Wizard Did It

Comment: They had wizard then? Blasphemy!

Comment: Xena is just really good at Snooker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the 2nd episode of the 5th season, "Chakram," it is explained that Ares, god of war, gave Xena the Chakram apparently at the time after the Battle of Corinth and Xena's venture to Northern Europe (Scandinavia).  However, one must note that in season one, Xena tells Ares that she used to wonder what he looks like, being the first time they actually met.  In the Hercules episode "Armagedon pt 2" when Iolaus travels to the past, we witness Ares talking to Xena in her tent (although it is not clear if he made himself visible to her).  In other Xena episodes from season 3 and on, Ares often talks about how he gave blood-thirsty Xena focus.

And back to the Chakram... It's a combination of Xena's motion awareness and mystic force.  In real life an aerodynamic object can ricochet once but will lose strength and speed afterwards so it's not possible to keep ricocheting, let alone go back to the thrower's hands.

Answer (score 8):

From the Xena wiki. http://hercxena.wikia.com/

In the [Chakram](http://hercxena.wikia.com/wiki/Chakram) entry:

> The Chakram is the trademark weapon of Xena's. Once thrown, it ricochets off objects and returns to the thrower, which requires a high level of reflexes to catch. Only four people have been seen to control the Chakram successfully.
>
> It is arguably the most iconic and mysterious thing in the Xenaverse. Not much is known about the weapon; It was possibly given to Xena by Ares, around about the time she left Chin and ventured towards Norway.

Further reading suggests it was a prized weapon of the gods, as they were constantly attempting to gain possession of them. The Light Chakram had the ability to kill gods, so it was guarded by Kal, one of the gods of war.

Eventually the Dark Chakram and Light Chakram were fused into one, which could split apart in flight to hit two different targets.

In a Universe with Greek and Roman gods intermingling with mortals, it is not hard for the suspension of disbelieve to suggest that the Chakram is a magical weapon, and its ability to ricochet until it returns to the thrower is just one of its properties.

Comment: Also, what DVK said.

Comment: Is it really so sad that a Hercules and Xena wiki exists? Those shows kept me completely bored many a night, preventing me from going out and doing anything _really_ stupid.

Comment: What is sad is there is a wiki for any subject. However, I decided to remove my comment from the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Xena has extremely good spatial awareness - the only magic involved is that it keeps ricocheting, rather than slowing down and falling.

Demonstrated in episode 3x02, *Been There, Done That* when Xena has to plan out the longest ricochet she's ever done.