# Is Captain America's shield magnetic?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

I believe his gauntlet is some sort of magnetic device (MCU), but is the shield itself magnetic in any way (both in comics and MCU)?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7171/how-does-captain-americas-shield-work. Indicates that his shield is not magnetic.

Comment: I meant to say that it indicated that his *gauntlet* is not magnetic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Is it capable of being affected by a magnetic field? Yes. Magneto has, in the past, affected Captain America's proto-adamantium shield quite easily.

[image]

- Does it possess a magnetic field of its own? No.
- Could one be induced artificially? Most likely. The alloys used to make it do not seem to be intrinsically anti-magnetic. In fact, this makes the shield which is normally invincible to almost any force, have a single vulnerability, magnetism.
- While magnetism cannot destroy the shield, it can be used to manipulate the shield at a distance.

Comment: How do you guys find these highly relevant comic references? Fantastic.